# Firefox, Ubuntu Gnome: Alt conflict with input method and HUD

Tags: gnome, keyboard, firefox, shortcut-keys

If i set up my keys in Ubuntu as Alt+Shift for change input method, it is conflict with "Hud" in Firefox wich try "open" menu. Its very annoining behavior, and i cant normally type on 2 languages.

i've already install add-on from Mozzila help link ( https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly ) , that can customize shortcuts, but i cant find there only this option with "Alt" all another exist. Also when i change inputs this bug make a new-line in comments on vk.com site so i need delete it ;(((

OS: ubuntu 16.04 server + gnome
Firefox 52.0.2 (64-bit)

Answer (score 5):

Found answer: 
type in adres bar
about:config
Hit Enter. Click Yes.
Then click on search string on this page. Type this (or paste it):
ui.key.menuAccessKeyFocuses

Then click on "true" to make it "false". Done, now when you push "Alt" key in firefox, menu dont appears and u can easy change language or make another action with Alt key.

Gratz!

Comment: FYI there is a [bug 1712200](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1712200) with Firefox on Wayland.

Comment: Sometimes menu bar in Firefox is helpful, so disabling it is not an ideal solution.

Comment: @user502144 sometims its like one time in century or 1000 years? :) I dont use this menu bar sience 2003-2005 year.  All settings i have in small menu, if i need save or something else i remember hotkeys. btw now in 18.04 no this annoying behavior. only if i push one alt menu appears.

Comment: @Amaroc So, how do you restore previous session after something went wrong? The only option I see is in menu bar. By the way you can use F10 instead of Alt to open menu bar, so this answer seems to work.