# Ubuntu 17.10, changing input switching to alt-shift (with gnome-tweaks) creates problem in firefox

Tags: firefox, 17.10, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, settings

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10, and when I tried to set my keyboard layout to change with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>, I hit a  [well known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322). There is [a workaround, using `gnome-tweaks-tool`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967364/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-cant-change-the-input-switching-shortcut-to-altshift) which works, but then it creates an unwanted behaviour on Firefox (perhaps other programs as well).

After setting <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> through `gnome-tweak-tool` as the combination to change language, whenever this combination is pressed within Firefox, it triggers a toggle that Firefox uses to show/hide the Menu Bar (with File/Edit/View etc.), and 'focus' is taken away from wherever the cursor was.

It's very frustrating, because one has to go and click again at the cursor.  The only solution I found was to permanently enable Menu Bar in Firefox because then <kbd>alt</kbd> doesn't do anything and I can use it to change languages. But I don't want to have Menu Bar on top always.

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to explain.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The bug does not seem to affect non-modifier keys.  Can you choose a non-modifier key, and would that be an acceptable workaround for you? For example `Menu`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't try, since one can simply avoid the menu 'focus' by simply using shift-alt instead of alt-shift (i.e. pressing shift first, then alt).

Comment: Similar issue is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/908144/firefox-ubuntu-gnome-alt-conflict-with-input-method-and-hud?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>shift</kbd> before <kbd>alt</kbd>) in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks pomsky - it worked! .. Such a simple solution.

Now all I have to do it to reprogram my hand not to use alt-shift :) 

PS - I tried to vote 'up' as the solution is good, but I can't, probably because I dont have enough 'reputation'.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with `slack`, after some digging found out that there is another way to change the keyboard layout w/o using `gnome-tweak-tool` which wont cause this side effect of losing the focus.

The solution is to use `gsettings` as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/986629/567424)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_L']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward "['<Alt>Shift_L']"
```